# How to improve this noisy plot of a numerical integral function?

Tags: numerical-integration

This code produces a very noisy plot of a smooth metric.  Increasing the MaxRecursion from 20 to 50 doesn't help.  MMa doesn't seem to use the smoothness of the function to refine its estimates of the function being plotted.  Is there any way to improve those plot?  I already tried the "try a bunch of random options" approach, and this was as good as it got.

```
gau[x_, v_] := Exp[-(x^2)/(2*v)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*v];
d = {0, 1, 2, 20, 21, 22};
m = Length[d];
f[x_, v_] := Total[gau[x - d, v]/m];
mln[v_] := NIntegrate[f[x, v]*Log[f[x, v]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 20, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"];
metric[v_] := Sum[Log[f[d[[i]], v]], {i, 1, m}]/m - mln[v] - 1/2;
Plot[metric[10^t], {t, -.585, -.565}]
```

EDIT:  A comment suggested I delete the Method part, but if I do that, I get completely wrong results for lower values of t, like around -2 < t < -1.  That's why I put the AQMC Method in there.

Comment: Just delete ` Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"` and it will be much smoother... and faster.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Thank you.  I edited the question to explain why I had to add that.

Comment: @JerryGuern, a plot of what you are expecting would help. A very fast method for your integrand would be `DoubleExponential`. It seems also that  $\nu> 0$, or even $\nu> b$, with $b$ a positive value greater than 0.001 or so, as when $\nu\rightarrow 0$ the integrand resembles a Dirac Delta function... All this also would help

Comment: Have you tried integrating by parts?

Comment: this is a 1-d integral. MonteCarlo is not called for at all and just saying you get "completely wrong" results without it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I see whats going on..consider the specific case `v=1/100`:

```
gau[x_] = Exp[-(x^2)/(2*(1/100))]/Sqrt[2*Pi*(1/100)];
d = {0, 1, 2, 20, 21, 22};
m = Length[d];
f[x_] = Total[gau[x - d]/m];
NIntegrate[f[x]*Log[f[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"]
```

> -0.908091

```
NIntegrate[f[x]*Log[f[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> -0.454056

Which is right?  Look at the integrand:

```
Plot[f[x]*Log[f[x]], {x, -25, 25}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The non zero parts correspond to the `d` values.  The default integrate "sees" the activity near the origin and the integrand appears to go to zero quickly, so it doesn't happen to sample the second set of peaks.

Knowing this we can force it to sample the interesting regions:

```
NIntegrate[f[x]*Log[f[x]], 
 Evaluate[{x, Sequence @@ Join[{-Infinity}, d, {Infinity}]}]]
```

> -0.908112

making that change in the original code:

```
Plot[metric[10^t], {t, -2, 0}]
```

[image]

comparison of this with original monte carlo method for the plot near the local minima.

[image]

note monte carlo is also considerably slower.  Also, ultimately you can get a good plot with montecarlo if you set a high PrecisionGoal, but then it takes a really long time.

Comment: You beat me to it, except for one thing. The Monte Carlo method still makes a jagged plot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ANKY8.png -- The default method seems to work much better. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2, right no monte carlo. Just `NIntegrate` without options and the `d` values listed in the integration domain.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood what you had done.  I thought you kept the Monte Carlo and only added `d`.

Answer (score 1):

A plot of the integrand is a bit weird. It has narrow peaks for $t\in(-2,2)$ and $x$ values around 0 and 20. Not sure about the reliability of your integral results, unless you have an idea of what you are expecting. Maybe someone specialised in numerical integration algorithms for this class of functions can help.

[image]

Anyway, I have tried with this. Although I get an error regarding the non-numerical evaluation at sampling points in the interval, it is very fast and gives a result, I do not know whether this is useful and accurate though:

```
mln[v_] := 
NIntegrate[f[x, v]*Log[f[x, v]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}, 
MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

[image]

### Additonal work

I have been investigating a bit more the sum of the function `metric` and `mln`, separately. I have worked in them as a function of $v$ only. First, I have sampled both functions from $10^{-3}$ to $10^{3}$, to get an interpolating function.

First, I get for the sum the following:

[image]

and in a small range:

[image]

for `mln` :

[image]
[image]

Both results seem to be smooth. Therefore, if we subtract to get the values for `metric`:

[image]

It seems that the local minimum predicted exists. However, there is a cup which is a bit bizarre, and I cannot explain:

[image]

Maybe, it comes from the numerical approximation for low values of $v$. We must remember that `metric` diverges for $v\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: This is giving a totally wrong result.  The metric has a local minimum in the range that I specified, and this method misses it.  If you extend the domain of t out to -2<t<2, you can see this method yields a plot with a discontinuity, which is just false.

Comment: @JerryGuern  What about your integrand I plot? Is it also wrong?

Comment: @JerryGuern I have gone further. Please, take a look at your convenience.